# Order the output using sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have this output after executing `diff`:

```
< #R1#Number = Gauge32: 258     Name = STRING: "TATA"
---
> #R1#Number = Gauge32: 280     Name = STRING: "TATA"
```

I need to implement a sed command in a shell script to have this output:

```
Hostname=R1; old=258 new=280, Name="TATA"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try Perl instead:

```
diff file1 file2 | 
    perl -lne 'if(/^(.).*?#(.+?)#.*?:\s*(\d+).*(".+?")/){
        $1 eq ">" ? print "Hostname=$2; old=$o new=$3, Name=$4" : ( $o=$3 )}'
```

#### Explanation

- The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call and the `-n` will cause the script given with `-e` to be applied to each line of the input file.
- The regular expression will identify the first character (`^.`), the first string between `#` (`#(.+?)#`), a `:` followed by 0 or more whitespace and a set of numbers (`:\s*(\d+)`) and the last quoted string on the line (`.*(".+?")`). The parentheses cause these to be saved as `$1` through `$4`.
- `foo ? bar : baz` : this is a C construct present in many languages. It is shorthand for "if foo is true, then do bar, else do baz". So, if `$1`, the first character of the line which was saved by the previous match operation, is `>`, then we will print and if it isn't, we will save the 3rd pattern matched as `$o`.

Or

```
diff file1 file2 | 
    perl -lane '$o = $F[4] if /^</; $F[1]=~s/#(.*)#.*/$1/; 
        print "Hostname=$F[1]; old=$o new=$F[4], Name=$F[8]" if />/'
```

#### Explanation

- The `-a` will cause Perl to automatically split each input line at whitespace and save it in the `@F` array.
- `$o = $F[4] if /^</;` : this saves the 5th field as `$o` if the first character of the line is `<`.
- `$F[1]=~s/#(.*)#.*/$1/;` : this will remove everything except the hostname from the second field (`$F[1]`, arrays are numbered from 0).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bash
diff ... | sed -n -e '
    /^< / h
    /^---/ H
    /^> / { H; x; s/\n//g;
            s/^< #\([^#][^#]*\)#Number = Gauge32: \([0-9][0-9]*\) .* #\1#Number = Gauge32: \([0-9][0-9]*\) .* Name = STRING: \("[^"]*"\).*/Hostname=\1; old=\2 new=\3, Name=\4/;
            p; }'
```

The idea is to get everything on a single line, then pick up only the interesting stuff.

In detail:

- `sed -n` - don't print anything by default
- `/^< / h` - copy lines starting with `<` to the hold space
- `/^---/ H` - append lines starting with `---` to the hold space
- `/^> / { ... }` - for lines starting with `>` do the following:
- `H` - append the line to the hold space
- `x` - exchange the hold space and the pattern space
- `s/\n//g` - remove newlines; at this point the pattern space holds something like this: `< #R1#Number = Gauge32: 258     Name = STRING: "TATA"---> #R1#Number = Gauge32: 280     Name = STRING: "TATA"`
- `s/.../.../` - format the output (nothing clever here, just plain `sed`-fu)
- `p` - print

This doesn't work for general `diff` output where changes can happen on adjacent lines.  But it does answer the question the way you asked it.